# MongoDB add a timestamp field and update it with existing isodate field

Tags: mongodb

datetime is my user-defined field where i m storing in isodate format. I want add a timestampCreated key to the documents in this collection.
I am trying this but its giving error as "error:timestamp must be in number".

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('test').find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
  var doc = cursor.next(); 
  db.getCollection('test').update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : 
{'timestampCreated' : new Timestamp(new Date('datetime'), 0) }});
}
```

Comment: `'datetime'` is a "string". You want `new Date(doc.datetime)` and you also don't want the `TimeStamp()` since that has a different purpose. Just use the `Date`.

Comment: datetime is user-defined field and its in isodate format

Comment: I know. But you are passing in a "string" to the `Date` constructor instead of a "value" from the document itself. Hence my correction as is also shown on the linked questions and answers.